# Gitlab - Problems with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, yaml, gitlab, gitlab-ci, android-constraintlayout

I'm starting on GitLab.

I am migrating my code and I'm trying to build my application but I receive the error below:

> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:   [Solver for ConstraintLayout 1.0.0-beta4,
> > ConstraintLayout for Android 1.0.0-beta4].   Before building your
> > project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the
> > installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK
> > Manager.   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license
> > agreements from one workstation to another, go to
> > http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

I'm trying a lot of alternatives but never resolved my problem.

Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/showcheap/android-ci:latest
variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "25"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "25.0.2"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "24.4.1"
before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.tgz https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.tgz
  - tar --extract --gzip --file=android-sdk.tgz
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-support
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew dependencies || true
stages:
  - deployDev
dev:
  stage: deployDev
  script:
    - ./gradlew incrementVersionCode
    - ./gradlew assembleRelease
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app-release.apk
  environment:
    name: development
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?